# Parallel requests are stalled even in HTTP 2

Tags: google-chrome, networking, http2, parallels, stalled

There are list of items in the array. For each Item we need to fetch data from the server on componentMount. All requests are triggered in parallel but the request are getting stalled. All requests use same connection id as well. The target domain is in HTTP 2 as well. Last request is stalled for almost 4s. Do anyone have any idea?

API calls:

[image]

Last call(almost stalled for 4s):

[image]

Request should not stalled.